# PHP Read object property value from file

Tags: php, file, object, readfile

I have file settings.js with that following structure:

```
var settings = {
    foo: 'fooValue',
    bar: 'barValue',
    ...
};
```

How can I read foo property value in my index.php file?

I tried this:

```
$settings_file = file_get_contents('.' . $settings);
$settings_content = json_decode($settings_file)
$fooValue = $settings_content->settings->foo;
```

but when I print $fooValue its empty.

Comment: if settings is on the same directory as the php file use **file_get_conents($settings);**

Comment: Of course, because it is not json.

Comment: @u_mulder its object, yes. Any tips how can I read it?

Comment: @Vidal I called file_exists to check if $settings exist and it returns true. Path is not a problem. Problem is my settings.js hold object variable and I am not sure how to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to use a regex to match the value.

This is a simple match of `foo:` optional space `'` or `"` content `'` or `"` comma, with the content being the only thing which is a capture group...

```
$settings_file = file_get_contents('.' . $settings);
preg_match('/foo:\s+["\'](.*)["\'],/', $settings_file, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

gives

```
fooValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading a json, you are reading a file that contains a variable declaration with an object in javascript.

your settings file have to be a valid json. The name and the value have quotes.

Example:

```
{
    "foo": "fooValue",
    "bar": "barValue",
    ...
}
```

[Reference on JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

Comment: Is there a way to read this variable? I'd like to keep settings file structure as is.

Comment: you can, but then you will have to write your own function to extract the contents, and you can not use **json_decode()** because is not a valid json